# Amazon MWS Reports API answers _DONE_NO_DATA_ instead of _CANCELLED_

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I'm using "Reports API" in MWS for get order information. I need billling information (billing address, ...) about Customers for using in CRM.

I use Report **[_GET_AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENTS_DATA_](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html)** because selling on FBA and this ReportType return billing information.

If I make 2 successive API requests. Status for second request will **_DONE_NO_DATA_**, but should [**_CANCELLED_**](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_guide/FBAGuide_DoNotRequestFBAReports.html).

Example Response:

```
<ReportRequestInfo>
  <ReportType>_GET_AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENTS_DATA_</ReportType>
  <ReportProcessingStatus>_DONE_NO_DATA_</ReportProcessingStatus>
  <EndDate>2016-12-08T14:06:49+00:00</EndDate>
  <Scheduled>false</Scheduled>
  <ReportRequestId>127509017143</ReportRequestId>
  <StartedProcessingDate>2016-12-08T14:07:16+00:00</StartedProcessingDate>
  <SubmittedDate>2016-12-08T14:06:49+00:00</SubmittedDate>
  <StartDate>2016-11-30T21:00:00+00:00</StartDate>
  <CompletedDate>2016-12-08T14:07:22+00:00</CompletedDate>
</ReportRequestInfo>
<ReportRequestInfo>
  <ReportType>_GET_AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENTS_DATA_</ReportType>
  <ReportProcessingStatus>_DONE_</ReportProcessingStatus>
  <EndDate>2016-12-08T14:06:48+00:00</EndDate>
  <Scheduled>false</Scheduled>
  <ReportRequestId>127508017143</ReportRequestId>
  <StartedProcessingDate>2016-12-08T14:06:53+00:00</StartedProcessingDate>
  <SubmittedDate>2016-12-08T14:06:48+00:00</SubmittedDate>
  <StartDate>2016-11-30T21:00:00+00:00</StartDate>
  <CompletedDate>2016-12-08T14:07:16+00:00</CompletedDate>
  <GeneratedReportId>4430367616017143</GeneratedReportId>
</ReportRequestInfo>
```

I do not know if there is no real data or a large number of requests to the API.
How do I know?

For requests I use the official library for Reports API  or scratchpad. Responses are equal.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to call [GetReport](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_GetReport.html) with the GeneratedReportId. This will return the data you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, but to get GeneratedReportId, need to make a request `GetReportRequestList`. If status ReportProcessingStatus `_DONE_` then it is possible to obtain `GeneratedReportId`, otherwise it is empty!

Comment: Ahh, I see. I didn't read the _CANCELLED_ link above. Sounds like Amazon has a bug as their implementation differs from the documentation. If you execute it every 30 minutes, do you get _DONE_, or sometimes _DONE_NO_DATA_?

Comment: After sending the first request  i get **_DONE_**, and 30 minutes **_DONE_NO_DATA**_ . After first request.
I always get **_DONE_NO_DATA**_ but should **_CANCELLED** _.